# Vaadin application unresponsive different browsers

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm using vaadin 7 and since yesterday my application gets unresponsive after clicking a button. I've run my application on localhost in different browsers (Chrome, IE, Safari) with the same result. In Chrome it just breaks down, asking me if I want to kill the page and in IE I got this message: "localhost not responding due to a long-running script". Does anyone have experienced the same problem?  I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: so what vaadin version is this?  is the app somewhere to test?  what have you changed since yesterday?  have you tried a git-bisect to find the problem?  have you debugged e.g. the click handler on that button?  or is the problem with any button? anything usefull from the devconsole in your browser?

Comment: What have you changed since it last worked? Please show the code which handles the click event